# How can I implement commit/rollback for MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, commit, rollback

Well basically I have this script that takes a long time to execute and occasionally times out and leaves semi-complete data floating around my database. (Yes I know in a perfect world I would fix THAT instead of implementing commits and rollbacks but I am forced to not do that)

Here is my basic code (dumbed down for simplicity):

```
$database = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=mysql_db","username","password");

while (notDone())
{
    $add_row = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES (?)");
    $add_row->execute(array('values'));

    //PROCESSING STUFF THAT TAKES A LONG TIME GOES HERE
}

$database = null;
```

So my problem is that if that if the entire process within that while loop isn't complete then I don't want the row inserted to remain there.  I think that somehow I could use commits/rollbacks at the beginning and end of the while loop to do this but don't know how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#11) on transactions with PDO.

Basically wrap the long running code in:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
...
$dbh->commit();
```

And [according to this PDO document page](http://usphp.com/manual/en/ref.pdo.php):

"When the script ends or when a connection is about to be closed, if you have an outstanding transaction, PDO will automatically roll it back.  "

So you will lose the transaction that was pending when the script timed out.

But really, you ought to redesign this so that it doesn't depend on the scriipt staying alive.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried it yet but I think that is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need to use InnoDB based tables for transactions then use any library like PDO or MySQLi that supports them.

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
    $mysqli->query("insert into tblbook (id,cid,book) values('','3','book3.1')");
    echo $q_ins=$mysqli->affected_rows."<br>";
    $mysqli->query("update tblbook set book='book3' where cid='3'");
    echo $q_upd=$mysqli->affected_rows."<br>";
    $mysqli->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $mysqli->rollback();
    echo $sql . '<br />' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
//This may help someone....This code commit the transactions
//only if both queries insert and update successfully runs

$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","user_name","password","db_name");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
    $mysqli->query("insert into tblbook (id,cid,book) values('','3','book3.1')");
    echo $q_ins=$mysqli->affected_rows."<br>";
    $mysqli->query("update tblbook set book='book3' where cid='3'");
    echo $q_upd=$mysqli->affected_rows."<br>";

    if($q_ins==1 && $q_upd==1)
    {
        $mysqli->commit();
        echo "Commit<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        $mysqli->rollback();
        echo "Rollback<br>";
    }
}
?>
```